# revert InvalidCalldata error VRFCoordinator

Tags: contract-debugging, oracles, error, chainlink, vrf

I am using a clone of the pancakeSwap lottery and attempting to use a write function. I keep getting an error in the BSC testnet VRFCoordinatorV2 contract saying revert InvalidCalldata();. The function I'm calling only takes a uint as an input, but somewhere along the line it checks if data.length == 32 and it's failing. Here is my failed tx:

https://dashboard.tenderly.co/tx/bsc-testnet/0xb7a702c3aaccf2f22a540687f385bcda586aa56124fcb4e747d1f434564dce73/debugger?trace=0.0.1.0.2.0.0

Why is this happening?

Comment: what values are you setting for _keHash and _seed param inputs? for _keyHash for BSC testnet it should be 0xd4bb89654db74673a187bd804519e65e3f71a52bc55f11da7601a13dcf505314. For seed it should be any not null value

Comment: Oh I was uisng 0xcaf3c3727e033261d383b315559476f48034c13b18f8cafed4d871abe5049186 which is the V1 keyHash. Could this explain the problem?

Comment: I switched keyhases to the one you listed, still same error.

Comment: what are you using for the seed phrase input parameter?

Comment: Are you referring to the requestRandomness() fxn? That input is not entered manually; it is a keccak256 hash of the lotteryId and currentTicketId, which is calculated by the lottery contract, and then passed to the RNG generator contract which does the rest.

Comment: ```// Request a random number from the generator based on a seed
        randomGenerator.getRandomNumber(uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_lotteryId, currentTicketId))));```

Comment: From tenderly, the seed is: ```105409183525425523237923285454331214386340807945685310246717412709691342439136```

Comment: hmm that should be fine. Can you please follow the steps in the docs (https://docs.chain.link/docs/get-a-random-number/) to deploy a simple VRF consumer contract, and see if you can get this successfully working on BSC? If it works, then we can slowly pick away at parts and see what the difference is thats causing it to not work

Comment: I may be wrong because I'm no expert, but the VRF coordinator contract mandates that if the seeds data.length is NOT equal to 32, then it is invalid data. The seed (posted above) has data.length > 32....  So this is why it's reverting??... I don't understand. This contract I'm working with is literally a direct clone of the pancakeSwap lottery contract with NO changes.